# How to call the setActive() function for different events

Tags: javascript

I want to add active class using below function:

```
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('pagesidebar2').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) {
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

This function is only applicable to a list within pagesidebar2 div.

```
<div id="pagesidebar2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Let's say I want to use the same function to add active class to:

```
<div id="pagesidebar3">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">uae</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ASIA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AFRICA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What changes should i make to the setActive() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use an array of things you want to add the class to, and iterate over it.  For instance, to do sidebars 2 and 3:

```
const idsOfThingsToSetActive = ['pagesidebar2', 'pagesidebar3'];
function setActive() {
  idsOfThingsToSetActive.forEach(id => {
    aObj = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) {
      if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
        aObj[i].className='active';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Another would be to *parameterize* (ie. add an argument to) your function, then call your function once for each thing you want to set active; @Gbr22 gave a good example of that in their answer.

Which approach you take is really a human concern: do you want a function that focuses several things, or a function that focuses one thing, and you use it multiple times?

The rest of your code might impact this: for instance, if you need to focus one or multiple elements *elsewhere*, besides onload, then you probably want to do things the same in both places so that you can re-use the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the navigation id, as an argument to your `setActive` function

```
function setActive(nav) {
  aObj = document.getElementById(nav).getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) {
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}
onload = ()=>{setActive('pagesidebar2'); setActive('pagesidebar3')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard-code the div `id`, you would **pass a reference to the `div` that you need to work on** as an argument to the function.

Also, take a look at this re-worked syntax. `getElementsByTagName()` is inefficient and even more so when used within a loop. [You should avoid using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) and instead use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). You can then directly loop over the resulting collection with [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which eliminates the need for loop indexes.

And, are you sure you want your `indexOf` check to compare against `0`? [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `-1` if an item can't be found. `0` is a valid answer that means the searched on element was present.

```
function setActive(div) {
  // Find all the <a> elements within the passed div reference and loop over them
  div.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(a){
    if(location.href.indexOf(a.href)>=0) {
      a.className='active';
    }
  }):
}

window.onload = setActive(document.getElementById("pagesidebar2"));

// Then any other time you want to call the function, just pass the appropriate div
setActive(document.getElementById("pagesidear3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class instead of an ID. This is a great option as you won't have to modify the javascript every time you need to loop through another set of links, just give the parent a class of "sidebar".

```js
function setActive() {
var _url = "https://stacksnippets.net/home.html";//document.location.href
  aObj = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) {
    if(_url.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}

setActive();
```

```css
.active{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" id="pagesidebar2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sidebar" id="pagesidebar3">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">uae</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ASIA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AFRICA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `querySelectorAll`

```js
function setActive() {
  let aObj = document.querySelectorAll('#pagesidebar2,#pagesidebar3  a');
  console.log(aObj);
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) {
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

```css
.active{ color:'red'}
```

```html
<div id="pagesidebar2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="pagesidebar3">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">uae</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ASIA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AFRICA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```